# None of my web services work after changing server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, .net-framework-version

Last week I changed the server of my ASP.net Application. Everything is fine except none of the web services seem to work. Nothing happens when the web service is being called from browser. I think there is problem with the IIS configuration or server settings.

I searched a lot in Google for this and did intensive debugging for weeks, yet with no solution. No web services work in my project since we changed server.

Is there any configuration that disables all web services? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: What kind of web services? asmx? wcf? rest? servicestack?

Comment: asmx. called from client script using $.ajax()

Comment: All web services are listed when I entering the URL directly in the address bar. I invoked web services by clicking on them and it returns the desired results. But nothing happens when calling from client script

Comment: Is the client script sending the request to the correct URL?

Comment: Yes. Its work fine on my old server

Comment: I meant, are you sure it sends the requests to the new server and does not attempt to send it to the old one?

Comment: Ya sure. I set the url like this
url: "../../WebService/WebService.asmx/getIAllWt"

Comment: I tried to find out the error using                              `error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }`. I got the error message : **Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/HelloWorld'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got it from here..
[Deploying ASMX webservice on iis 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416020/asmx-service-works-on-development-server-returns-404-when-deployed-to-iis-7-5)

Thanks a lot @Frank.
Thank you Mr Joachim Isaksson For your comments