# Services not found in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis

I have a simple website, which I am hosting on IIS 7.5 along with Windows 7.
The problem is it's saying services not found. I have a web service under the project.

[image: The Path is as follows]

The web config is as follows:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416020/asmx-service-works-on-development-server-returns-404-when-deployed-to-iis-7-5 ; also : http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2520479

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IIS solved the issue.