# ASMX operation 404s, but ASMX service description doesn't, url routing issue?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, asmx, url-routing, webforms

So I've found myself with a conundrum.  We have some old asmx web services in our app that have worked fine for ages.

All of the sudden they stopped working on the build server (CI). I say stopped working, because even though the service description displays when I navigate to the service, invoking any operation doesn't get routed to the service (Web Form Routing).  There are 2 strange issues that arose in my attempt to fix this problem.

1.) After shelving all my pending changes, grabbing latest from TFS, and doing a local build (*which unless I'm mistaken, will get me what is on the build server since we build/push with each check in*). I noticed that I can't duplicate the error locally.

2.) Even though I can't duplicate the error locally, I still suspect routes, however the routes for all our services are added to the table first, and look like this : `"{service}.asmx/{*pathInfo}"`, I guess this was added as a safety precaution as something like *MyService.svc* shouldn't even make it to the router, as the file actually exists, though I'm not sure if that rule applies for *MyService.svc/MyMethod*

I'm not really sure how to test routing, i.e. where to set a break point to know if I'm going through the route table for a particular request or not, so any pointers in that area would be appreciated, as well as any other ideas as to why this might be happening.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASMX service works on development server, returns 404 when deployed to IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5416020/50447)

Answer (score 7):

I've just encountered the same error, after stumbling over this SO entry:

[Handlers returns 404 error on IIS7.5 integrated pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498723/handlers-returns-404-error-on-iis7-5-integrated-pipeline)

and tried the solution of adding the asmx handler to the web.configs webServer section all was well:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" name="asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hours wasted and all I needed was this?  X(